# ALLEXCEPT function does not work with filter

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to calculate the average report execution time per report. I created measure for average execution time.

```
AverageExecutionTime = CALCULATE(AVERAGE('Long Running Report'[TotalTime]),ALLEXCEPT('Long Running Report','Long Running Report'[ReportName]))
```

Data has one column called ReportPath which I am using as filter. when I don't filter on ReportPath measure shows correct average value per report.

[image]

When I filter on ReportPath it shows wrong values.

[image]

Expected result should be as below:

[image]

I know this is happening because of ALLEXCEPT(ReportName) but is there any way to include filter as well. There could be more than one filter on dashboard in any case it should display correct average.

I am using DirectQueryMode cannot use FILTER.

Comment: Does adding `ALLSELECTED(ReportName)` as a 2nd `CALCULATE` argument help at all?

Comment: @AlexisOlson It does calculate average execution time per report when there is no filter applied.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how that answers my question. Also, please include in your post what you expect to see when you use the slicer.

Comment: @AlexisOlson Updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this measure:

```
AveExecTime = CALCULATE(AVERAGE(LongRR[TotalTime]),
                  FILTER(ALLSELECTED(LongRR),
                      LongRR[ReportName] IN VALUES(LongRR[ReportName])))
```

The `ALLSELECTED` function preserves the slicer setting and then we say the `ReportName` must be in the current filter context (equal to the value you have in that table row).